# Timer tick doesn't work

Tags: c#, console-application

I having problem with my timer, it doesn't reach its `tick` and I don't see the problem.

```
class Class1
{
    bool check;
    Timer net;
    private bool timerComplete = false;
    private int timerIndex = 0;

    public Class1()
    {
        check = true;
        net = new Timer();
    }
    public void Do()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4*1*1000);
        net.Interval = 1 * 1000;
        net.Tick+=new EventHandler(net_Tick);
        net.Start();
        while (!timerComplete)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }

    void net_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerIndex++;
        if (timerIndex >= 10)
        {
            timerComplete = true;
            return;
        }
       //my code
    }
}
```

**Main**

This is where I call the `Do()` function

```
class Program
{
    const int SW_HIDE = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hide();
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        c.Do();
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
        // Hide
        ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
}
```

Comment: Does the program exit before the tick gets called? Is this a console, windows or web application?

Comment: Sorry for miss this important info,it is console and yes it exit before the tick get called

Comment: What particular timer class are you using?  (From what namespace?)

Comment: Display the code (probably in program.cs) that instantiates this class and calls `Do()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing but basically you are looking for the following

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var myObject = new Class1();
    myObject.Do();

    // give the program 10 minutes to run. This is arbitrary so you will want to change
    //     to something realistic or have a callback to signal "done".
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

That should do it or at least get you started!

**Other Note** - One other note is the second timer calls a method named `net_Tick`. I don't see this in the code presented so I assume there are no issues with that...

**Alternative Approach**

One other approach instead of making the main thread pause is to block the `Do` method until the timer is done (or you want to stop). To do this I have added just the pieces of code that need to change in `Class1` below:

```
public class Class1 {

    // add a variable for timer complete
    private bool timerComplete = false;
    private int timerIndex = 0;


    public void Do()
    {
        t.Enabled = true;

        // start timer same as normal:
        t.Interval = 10 * 1000;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();

        // busy wait to block the thread
        while (!timerComplete) {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // give this a stopping point
        timerIndex++;
        if (timerIndex >= 10) {
            timerComplete = true;
            return;
        }

        // leave the rest of the tick as it was before...
    }
}
```

Once you do this you can remove the call to `Sleep` from the `Main` routine and everything should still work. Best of luck!

Comment: @user2451001 I put the main thread to sleep. This will keep the program alive until the tick has a chance to fire. As soon as the main thread exits windows will end up killing all other threads. I would guess this is your core issue.

Comment: @user2451001 I added another alternative approach to the problem if you are interested. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `Do()`, which is the method that sets the timer's properties and starts it.

EDIT:

If it's your second timer the one that doesn't work (you still don't specify which timer is not working), it's because you are creating it and not saving any reference to it, therefore you lose control over it.

Comment: At Program.Main i create a new instance of class1 and right after im calling Do()

Comment: The OP can be calling `Do` outside of the code presented (as they just commented)

Comment: Then don't mislead by omitting it. You didn't mention that in your original post. You also don't specify which tick is not called.

Comment: I edited the answer providing a possible explanation.